# Facebook 500 Internal Server Error -> /dialog/feed

Tags: facebook, internal-server-error

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=128738460473752&link=http://videos.sapo.pt/fiLm1Zo3kiTzFUIoWYtU&feature=share&display=popup&redirect_uri=http://videos.sapo.pt/fiLm1Zo3kiTzFUIoWYtU?post_id
```

This url is giving me a internal server error (http://videos.sapo.pt/fiLm1Zo3kiTzFUIoWYtU).

Comment: You're using duplicate `?`... Still a 500 error

Comment: Ok i change the redirect_uri and the link to url encode and check the app facebook settings and everythink is ok.

Answer (score 2):

The sample link provided at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/feed-dialog/v2.2#redirect

works for me:

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=145634995501895&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption&link=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Fdocs%2F%20&redirect_uri=https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

but

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=128738460473752&display=popup&caption=An%20example%20caption&link=http%3A%2F%2Fvideos.sapo.pt%2FfiLm1Zo3kiTzFUIoWYtU&redirect_uri=http://videos.sapo.pt/fiLm1Zo3kiTzFUIoWYtU

doesn't. Please check that

1. You app with the id `128738460473752` has configured `http://videos.sapo.pt` as a valid URL
2. URL Encode the link parameter

Comment: Ok i change the redirect_uri and the link to url encode and check the app facebook settings and everythink is ok.

Answer (score 0):

URL encoding the link parameter doesn't work anymore.
Facebook is now returning an error inside the popup if you do it.

You don't have to URL encode your link parameter, but you can just leave it as text.